# Database Model for Job Application Portal

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I need to implement a Job Application Platform for a fictive company in a University Project.

The Website is for a single company, not multiple companies like indeed.

Every potential applicant has to make an account and then he is able to apply for the jobs he wants to.

I came up with a model for the database and wanted to ask for feedback and potential improvement since I am very uncertain if it is good enough.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DVWB.png

The tables are in German so here is a translation:

Job advertisements (upper left)

1. ID (PK)
2. Department
3. title
4. Startdate of application time (if this date is reached the advertisement is visible on the website)
5. Enddate (if this date is reached it automatically gets hidden)
6. Description
7. Type of job (internship, full-time etc)
8. isActive (boolean if the adv. is visible)
9. Location
10. contact
11. CV
12. Anschreiben, Zeugnisse & weitere Doks is a boolean
    -> when it is true those documents are required
    -> release (HR has to check every advertisement and has to release them)

- Employees (upper middle)

1. ID
2. Firstname
3. Lastname
4. Email
5. role

- External registrations (upper left - all accounts who register for the job portal)

1. ID
2. Firstname
3. Lastname
4. email
5. phonenumber

- Applications (lower middle table)

1. ID (PK)
2. Job advertisement ID (FK)
3. Applicant ID (FK - ID from external registrations)
4. Firstname
5. Lastname
6. email
7. phonenumber
8. status (shows if applications is being looked at and stuff)
9. Files (boolean to check if a zip file was uploaded with the application)

So my thought behind this model were that if some applies for a job & fills out the application form the userID of this account & the advertisement ID of the particular job get saved into the database "applications". This way it is always identifiable who applied to which job.

Comment: Why does a job portal need to know employees? Why does an application have a first name? Why does a job advert have a CV? Conceptually a job portal needs minimally a list of jobs, a list of users, and a list of users who have applied to jobs (an application). You seem to have this, plus some fluff, and some of your naming is a bit wonky (imho)

Comment: @CaiusJard we received a scenario from our Prof and that's the stuff he wrote in it, so I don't really have a choice there :/

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JobAdvertisement

- If `IsActive` is only related with `StartDate` and `EndDate` you should remove it and just check if inside time period.
- Consider modelling Department, Location, Contact using additional tables.
- Try finding a key and remove the surrogate
- Consider using a reference table for the `TypeOfJob` attribute.

Application

- Remove the surrogate ID and just use a composite PK that consists of the `JobAdvertisement` and `ExternalRegistration` keys.
- Remove FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber. You have all this in `ExternalRegistration`.
- Consider using a reference table for the `Status` attribute.